# JADE and JDBC MySQL connection giving classnotfound exception

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, classnotfoundexception, agents-jade

```
protected void setup() {
     System.out.println("Hello Buyer Agent "+getAID().getName()+" is now ready....");
     String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
     String dbName = "testdb";
     String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     String userName = "root";
     String password = "pass";

      try {
           Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
           Statement st = conn.createStatement();
           ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  requested_electric_prods ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1");
           while (res.next()) {
                elec_pro_name = res.getString("search_string");
                elec_pro_requested_min_price  = res.getInt("price_min");
                elec_pro_requested_max_price = res.getInt("price_max");
                System.out.println("Customer requested, product: "+ elec_pro_name + " min price: "+ elec_pro_requested_min_price + " max price: " + elec_pro_requested_max_price);
           }

           conn.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

This is my setup method. It is really simple. But still when it tries to connect to database it gives classNotFoundException.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I have JDBC driver and already added it to build path. I am using Eclipe and EJADE plugin. Does anyone know why it is happening? Are there any more configurations needed to do before starting the agent?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem had been some kind of a incompatibility between the EJADE plugin and Eclipse latest version: Juno. I changed to Eclipse Indigo and everything worked fine!